# Running Into Issues Access Console On Google Appengine 1.5.4

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm running into the following issue when trying to activate our console on Google Appengine.

> WARNING:root:No ssl package found. urlfetch will not be able to validate SSL certificates.
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "manage.py", line 18, in 
>       InstallAppengineHelperForDjango()
>     File "/Users/franklinkho/Workspace/mopub/server/appengine_django/**init**.py", line 550, in InstallAppengineHelperForDjango
>       LoadAppengineEnvironment()
>     File "/Users/franklinkho/Workspace/mopub/server/appengine_django/**init**.py", line 212, in LoadAppengineEnvironment
>       appconfig, unused_matcher, _ = dev_appserver.LoadAppConfig(PARENT_DIR, {})
>   ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack

Does anyone know why this is occurring?

Answer (score -1):

So this is an issue with your version of GAE, its trying to unpack more values than is there.  The patch is to set the retun of `LoadAppConfig` to be two parameters, the first is the appconfig and the other you can disregard.

```
appconfig, unused_matcher = dev_appserver.LoadAppConfig(PARENT_DIR, {})
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. My settings are like so: appconfig, unused_matcher, _ = dev_appserver.LoadAppConfig(PARENT_DIR, {})